# ASP Ajax control toolkit - on date selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got a calendar control on a text box I'm just wondering how I can trigger a sub when a date is chosen on the calendar?

There is a OnClientDateSelection changed in the extenders properties but im not sure how to use this.

Any help most appreciated! -- Jonesy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually post back your form with some client side javascript.  Then you could just check the selected date to do what you want.

```
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID="myButton" runat="server" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateChanged"></cc1:CalendarExtender>

    function dateChanged() {
       document.forms[0].submit();
    }

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
   If txtDate.Text <> String.Empty Then DoSomething
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
  'do your work
End Sub
```